# OnClick opens new windows but also changes current window

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm using IE8.  I've setup the following link:

```
<a href="terms.html" onclick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=400,height=600')" />Terms & Conditions</a>
```

When I click it.  I get the pop up the way I want.  But it also sets the current windows to the same URL.  I know I'm missing something silly.  Just can figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: consider changing the `href` to something other than the url (`#` for example), and pass the url directly into the `window.open` first argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add **return false;** after window.open like below :

```
<a href="terms.html" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'targetWindow', 'toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=400,height=600');return false;" />Terms & Conditions</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're clicking a `<a>`-link, your browser will automatically follow it. You need to make the onclick method return false for it to not open that page in your current window. It's also good to extract all JavaScript code from HTML, so that's something you should look into. However, this solution seems to do the trick:

**HTML**

```
<a href="terms.html" onclick="return openWindow('terms.html')" />Terms & Conditions</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function openWindow(href) {
  window.open(href,'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=400,height=600');
  return false;
}
```